# Python KeyError: 'destinationAccount'

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

i've code with the following structure from a website i'm **scraping** data:

```
destinationAccount:
   ownerBuilding: ( collapse to destinationAccount)
     label: ( collapse to ownerBuilding )
     _id: ( collapse to ownerBuilding )
vban: ( collapse to destinationAccount)
_id: ( collapse to destinationAccount)
```

When I try to read this Key with this

```
vban = str(transaction["destinationAccount"]["vban"])
```

It gives me `KeyError: 'destinationAccount'`

Anyone have an Idea why this comes up? When I run my Code, it will copy everything I need into the MySQL Database but as I already said, the KeyError popup and the Interval isn't working

```
sched = BlockingScheduler()
sched.add_job(start, 'interval', seconds=5)
sched.start()
```

because it stop runing after the error appears. When I comment out this one `vban = str(transaction["destinationAccount"]["vban"])` no error is coming up. I checked now more than 10 times, the structure is there on the website as I showed at the top. Any solution would be amazing.

```
def getData():
    databaseConn = dbConnect()
    cursor = databaseConn.cursor()

    for x in range(3):
        x = x * 25
        transactions = json.loads(makeRequest("URL.bla/transactions?offset=" + str(x), authToken, True).text)
        for transaction in transactions:
            person = ""
            try:
                person = transaction["destinationAccount"]["ownerCharacter"]["name"]
            except:
                try:
                    person = transaction["destinationAccount"]["ownerFactory"]["label"]
                except:
                    try:
                        person = transaction["destinationAccount"]["ownerBuilding"]["label"]
                    except:
                        person = str("unbekannt")

            reference = ""
            try:
                reference = str(translateTable[transaction["reference"]])
            except:
                reference = str(transaction["reference"])

            vban = str(transaction["destinationAccount"]["vban"])
            amount = str(transaction["amount"])
            taxAmount =str(transaction["taxAmount"])
            gesamt = (float(amount) + float(taxAmount))

            created = parse(str(transaction["created"]))
            date = str(created.date())
            time = str(created.time()).split(".")[0]

            sql = "INSERT INTO finanzen (transaktion, date, time, sendto, vban, amount, tax, gesamt, text) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
            val = (str(transaction["uuid"]), date, time, str(person), vban, amount, taxAmount, gesamt, reference)
            try:
               cursor.execute(sql, val)
               databaseConn.commit()
            except:
                print("Fehler Datenbank")
    dbClose(databaseConn,cursor)
```

Print result :

```
{'_id': 'CENSORED', 
'uuid': 'CENSORED', 
'amount': 11.8421, 
'taxAmount': 3.1479, 
'type': 'digital', 
'created': 'Date', 
'reference': 'CENSORED', 
'sourceAccount': {'_id': 'CENSORED', 
'ownerCharacter': {'_id': 'CENSORED', 
'name': 'NAME'}, 
'vban': 'NUMBER'}, 
'destinationAccount': {'_id': 'CENSORED', 
'vban': 'NUMBER', 
'ownerBuilding': {'_id': 'CENSORED', 
'label': 'Eclipse Towers'}}}
```

Comment: Please paste the python code you run

Comment: Edited to main post.

Comment: Please print `transactions` after `transactions = json.loads(makeRequest("URL.bla/transactions?offset=" + str(x), authToken, True).text)` and update question

Comment: Updated. But as I said, this I tested already but can't find any error at all.

Comment: what is the `[` on the start of the print? Is this a list? where is the `]`?

Comment: There is more entries, but they look all the same, if I post them all here this will explod on the site so I cut it.

Answer (score 1):

Difficult without seeing the full list but I suspect some of the items are missing the key.  Have you tried a check on the key existing.  Using your example:

```
transaction = {
   "_id":"CENSORED",
   "uuid":"CENSORED",
   "amount":11.8421,
   "taxAmount":3.1479,
   "type":"digital",
   "created":"Date",
   "reference":"CENSORED",
   "sourceAccount":{
      "_id":"CENSORED",
      "ownerCharacter":{
         "_id":"CENSORED",
         "name":"NAME"
      },
      "vban":"NUMBER"
   },
   "destinationAccount":{
      "_id":"CENSORED",

      "ownerBuilding":{
         "_id":"CENSORED",
         "label":"Eclipse Towers"
      }
   }
}

if 'vban' in transaction['destinationAccount']:
    vban = str(transaction["destinationAccount"]["vban"])
else:
    vban = "none"
```

Comment: The key definitely exists. At the top of my question I also wrote that when I execute everything works, this KeyError comes anyway. Everything is copied into the database as intended. There is always a number, there are no entries where this number is not available. Because they are transfers.

Comment: btw the solution you gave it gives the same error and also the full list is in the first post, it just keeps repeating over and over with other numbers, names.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Johnny John Boy for the Hint.

```
            vban = ""
            try:
                vban = str(transaction["destinationAccount"]["vban"])
            except:
                try:
                    vban = str(transaction["sourceAccount"]["vban"])
                except:
                    vban = str("Unbekannt")
```

This is the solution to fix the KeyError because there was a second part. now it works as it should without any error.